# R - function input and optimization

Tags: r, matrix, sum, mathematical-optimization

I usually have trouble inputing functions in R but they are always simple functions that I manage to work it out. However now I have a very complicated problem at hand that requires functions that has unknowns, summation and a matrix. And I am clueless where to begin. (This is not my homework question, just trying to work out something using a different method, hoping it works)

---

So I want to input a function:
A=∑<sub>i=1</sub> <sup>N</sup>   exp ^ [ ∑<sub>j=1</sub> <sup>M</sup>   Matrix <sub>ij</sub> * unknown<sub>j</sub>  ]

and then minimize the function:
B= log A - ∑<sub>j=1</sub> <sup>M</sup> unknown <sub>j</sub> * C <sub>j</sub>

so my goal is to find the j unknown parameters that minimizes function B.

---

But this is very complicated. You do not have to give me an answer directly. You can use another example to answer my question indirectly. Any help/tips/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: are `M` and `N` the dimensions of `Matrix`? Have you "translated" this into some R code?

Comment: Yes M and N are dimentions of the matrix. And I tried but I got stuck since in A the second summation is within the exponent, so cant use the usual double summation and then what do I do with the unknowns (vector)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if we can break the problem into smaller things:

Let's name some variables first:

- Let `Q` be an matrix with `N` rows and `M` columns
- Let `x` be a (column) vector of length `M` (for a moment, think it's not an "unknown")
- Let `C` be a (column) vector of length `M`

Notice that both `A` and `B` will be "scalars" (or, in R parlance, 1x1 vectors).

**Hint:** In R, you can do matrix multiplication using the `%*%` operator. See [Quick-R: Matrix algebra](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/matrix.html).

*Working on function `A`*

`Q %*% x` is the product inside the sum which is inside the exponential function, so:

```
A <- function (Q, x) {
  y <- Q %*% x # This will be a (column) vector of length `N`
  return(sum(exp(y)) # This will be a scalar (more precisely, a 1x1 vector)
}
```

Not so hard, is it?

*Working on function `B`*

```
B <- function(Q, C, x) {
  y <- sum(x * C) # or, since both x and C are column vectors:
                  # y <- t(x) %*% C
  a <- A(Q, x)
  return(log(a) - y)
}
```

So, that's how you would input the functions.

As for the optimization, I suggest you take a look to the [`optimx` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimx/index.html); you'll need to supply starting values for vector `x`.

Comment: Wow!!!! that simple? OMG I am banging my head since so long. Thank you!!!. Yes I did look into the optimx package. But I do not specifically have starting values of the unknown vector. But let me try to work on it. Maybe I am missing something in my interpretation. Thank you once again!!

Comment: @mac happy to help! By the way, if you find this answer useful, up-vote it, and if it solves your problem, accept it.

Comment: @mac Also, if you want to do some symbolic calculus with R, you may want to look to [this question (at Cross Validated) and its answers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/symbolic-computation-in-r)

Comment: @mac If you have a new question, please post it *as a question*. Maybe I'll be able to help you, and also many others around. Include some test data in your question to make your problem reproducable. Please read [Help center: How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)